# c# - Adding new parent node to existing Xml File

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml file and want to add a new parent node after the last existing node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuite id="" name="Test Projekt test">
  <node_order />
  <details />
  <testsuite id="" name="Test Suite 1">
    <node_order />
    <details />
    <testsuite id="" name="Test Suite Operation 2">
      <node_order />
      <details />
    </testsuite>
  </testsuite>
</testsuite>
<new node here>
```

i tryed to use the following code but it didn´t worked

```
XmlElement testsuite = doc_save.CreateElement("testsuite");
XmlAttribute ID = doc_save.CreateAttribute("id");
XmlAttribute Name = doc_save.CreateAttribute("name");
XmlElement node_order = doc_save.CreateElement("node_order");
XmlElement details = doc_save.CreateElement("details");

doc_save.DocumentElement.AppendChild(testsuite);
testsuite.Attributes.Append(ID);
testsuite.Attributes.Append(Name);
testsuite.AppendChild(node_order);
testsuite.AppendChild(details);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just serialize your object ? It will give you a proper XML

Comment: that would be not a valid `xml`.  you can only have one root node.

Comment: you need a new root node like `<testsuits>... <testsuits> ` inside that you could add more than one `<testsuite>` nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by @hotfix, rename your root element and when I ran your code it was working for me. See the XML and code I was using below.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuites id="" name="Test Projekt test">
  <node_order />
  <details />
  <testsuite id="" name="Test Suite 1">
    <node_order />
    <details />
    <testsuite id="" name="Test Suite Operation 2">
      <node_order />
      <details />
    </testsuite>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite id="" name="">
    <node_order />
    <details />
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Code:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(@"your\xml\file");

XmlElement testsuite = document.CreateElement("testsuite");
XmlAttribute ID = document.CreateAttribute("id");
XmlAttribute Name = document.CreateAttribute("name");
XmlElement node_order = document.CreateElement("node_order");
XmlElement details = document.CreateElement("details");

document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(testsuite);
testsuite.Attributes.Append(ID);
testsuite.Attributes.Append(Name);
testsuite.AppendChild(node_order);
testsuite.AppendChild(details);

document.Save(@"your\xml\file");
```